# Choosing how far you scroll before a jquery animate activates

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate

I have this code

```
$(window).load(function () {
            $elem1 = $('#div1');
            $elem2 = $('#div2');
            var scrollState = 'top';
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
                if ((scrollPos != 0) && (scrollState === 'top')) {
                    $elem1.stop().animate({
                        opacity: '1.0'
                    }, 300);
                    $elem2.stop().animate({
                        marginLeft: '50px'
                    }, 300);
                    scrollState = 'scrolled';
                } else if ((scrollPos === 0) && (scrollState === 'scrolled')) {
                    $elem1.stop().animate({
                        opacity: '0.0'
                    }, 300);
                    $elem2.stop().animate({
                        marginLeft: '0px'
                    }, 300);
                    scrollState = 'top';
                }
            });
}); //]]>
```

When I scroll down the page the jquery activates as soon as you start scrolling. I would like to be able to choose how far down the page you go before it activates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do a check on the value of scrollPos?

```
if(scrollPos > X && (scrollState === 'top')) {
    //activate
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: Need anything else? If that's all you need could you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: i had to use greater than or less than symbols                        if ((scrollPos >= 500) && (scrollState === 'top')) {                  
                            //activate
                        scrollState = 'scrolled';
                    } else if ((scrollPos < 500) && (scrollState === 'scrolled')) {
                            //do nothing
                    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(document).scrollTop()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)) to find out how far down you have scrolled.